# IONIC 3 -sobreescribe las apps

Tags: ionic2, ionic-framework

Hola soy nuevo en ionic 3  y el problema  que me genera es que  al instalar una apk en android todo trabaja bien pero al instalar otra esta  toma a la nueva como actualizacion y la sobreescribe eliminando  la que yo tenia previamente lo mas logico pense  era porq tenian el mismo nombre que en este caso ionic lo genera con "MyApp" asi q solo hice un cambio en el config.xml y  le di otro nombre
bueno el problema no se soluciono sigue suprimiendo a las apps  previas asi tengan otro nombre  u diferente contenido  seguro pase algo por alto.
espero alguien tenga alguna solución

Comment: Qué bien que lo solucionaste! =) Para que sirva de utilidad a futuros lectores deberías crear una respuesta (y quitar la respuesta de la pregunta). Saludos!

Comment: si ya lo corregí gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUCION]
me tomo tiempo pero ya esta solo se nececita cambiar el "id" del package en el config.xml asi puedes tener mas de 1 aplicacion con diferentes versiones sin que se borren las anteriores :D

Comment: @Hola he creado una app en Ionic 3 pero no tengo el archivo config.xml